# How to maximize the size, width and height, of an embedded Google Sheet or Doc?

Tags: iframe

How do I change the size, width and height, of an embedded Google Sheet or Doc? I didn't find a direct answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

The height and width parameters need to go inside the iframe tag, not in the URL.

```
<iframe width=600 height=500 src=......></iframe>
```

The way to get it to maximized is:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/abcdddddddddddddddd/pubhtml?gid=96612680&amp&single=true&amp;widget=true&amp;headers=false&chrome=true"</iframe>
```

Or with a style attribute:

```
<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%;" src=......"></iframe>
```